# Necessary condition for a sparse optimal point

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

In the paper [Sparsity Constrained Nonlinear Optimization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.4580), the following is being optimized:
$$
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \|x\|_0\leq s} f(x)
$$
where $\|x\|_0$ is the number of nonzero elements.

Theorem 2.1. states the necessary condition for the optimal point $x^*$ which is $\nabla f(x^*)=0$ if $\|x^*\|_0<s$ and $\nabla_{supp(x^*)} f(x^*)=0$ if $\|x^*\|_0=s$ where $\nabla_{supp(x^*)}$ is restriction of the gradient to the elements of $supp(x^*)$.

---

**Question**:

Why $\nabla_{supp(x^*)} f(x^*)=0$ if $\|x^*\|_0=s$?

---

**My understanding:**

The proof for $\nabla f(x^*)=0$ if $\|x^*\|_0<s$ totally makes sense, but why suddenly gradient over the support should be zero when the number of nonzero elements is equal to $s$.